# Problems with backslash on Windows and React Native run-android command

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run my app on an Android emulator under Windows 10. I already have the following variables set in my environment:

[image]

[image]

When executing the command, these error messages appear:

[image]

[image]

I had the emulator running at that moment and I also tried out the `emulator` command successfully.

So, I guess it got lost with the backslashes in the path. First, because it is treating the whole SDK path as a command and also because it is appending "platform-tools/adb" to the path. Please, any solutions?

Comment: Same issue here, did you get around it?

Comment: It seems that it was Node version being the latest and I needed LTS.

Comment: Tried 12.22.1 and 14.17.0 didn't work out :( Thanks for feedback!