# React native windows - script mixes slash and backslash in command path

Tags: windows, react-native

On windows react native cannot start up the app.
It seems as the script is mixing backslash and slash in the path to the executable abd.

ANDROID_HOME and PLATFORM_TOOLS are set correctly

[image: error iage]

Already tried differnt 12 and 14 [Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67609982/problems-with-backslash-on-windows-and-react-native-run-android-command)

Comment: so? Windows accepts either one and even mixed.

Answer (score 0):

This only happens when ANDROID_HOME is [set](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/packages/platform-android/src/commands/runAndroid/getAdbPath.ts).
try removing that environment variable. Worked like a charm for me.